# AWK to replace a line starts with in big file

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, gnu-parallel

I would like to replace a line in file which start with the content of variable `$cont`, using `awk`.

```
5473  12G Ju 2 06:32 part3
5423  11G Ju 6 07:32 part4
573  11G Ju 2 08:21 part5
5473  11G Ju 6 09:12 part6
5423  1G Jl 6 09:32 part7
```

I'm using `sed` now but taking too much time to do the same.

`sed` code is given below.

Now I'll find and delete the line starts with `$cont` and write the `$cont` to the file.

```
cont="foo"
 newLineCont ="this is new line"
    parallel -a test.txt -k --block 30M --pipe-part "sed -i /^$cont/d" test.txt
      echo $newLineCont >> test.txt
```

wanted to search and replace lines in the file which starts with the content of the variable $cont by content of $newLineCont using AWK

Comment: your question is not clear.. you want replace the contents of the file ? $cont with $newLineCont ?

Comment: try without parallel it might go faster

Comment: Note that looking for `^54` would also find the lines starting with e.g. `5473`.

Comment: @Kamaraj I wanted to search and replace lines in the file which starts with the content of the variable $cont by content of $newLineCont

Comment: @Juhan You want to replace _the whole line_ or just the number at the start?

Comment: @Kamaraj whole line

Answer (score 1):

Replacing each whole line with `$newLineCont` if the first whitespace-delimited field is equal to `$cont`:

```
awk -v c="$cont" -v nc="$newLineCont" '$1 == c { $0 = nc } 1' <infile >outfile
```

This will read from `infile` and create a new file called `outfile`.  If a line's first field is equal to `$cont`, the whole line will be replaced by `$newLinecont`.

The trailing `1` is a short way of writing `{ print }` and will cause all lines to be outputted.

---

Taking [Stéphane Chazelas comment below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460012/awk-to-replace-a-line-starts-with-in-big-file#comment836590_460024) into account (in cases where one or both of your variables contain backslashes):

```
env c="$cont" nc="$newLineCont" awk '$1 == ENVIRON["c"] { $0 = ENVIRON["nc"] } 1' <infile >outfile
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
sed "s/^$cont[^0-9].*/$newLineCont/" <infile >outfile
```

With `sed`, we have to be more careful to match the correct thing with out regular expression.  If `$cont` is `12`, we do *not* want to match lines starting with `123`.  This is why I explicitly match a non-digit after `$cont` with `[^0-9]` (I'm assuming `$cont` is a number).

As with the `awk` command, this reads from `infile` and writes to `outfile`.

If `$cont` or `$newLineCont` contains slashes, these would have to be escaped as `\/`, and if `$cont` contains any other character that is special in regular expressions, these would also need to be escaped properly.

Comment: That assumes `$cont` and `$newLineCont` don't contain backslash characters (and of course that `$cont` doesn't contain blanks or newlines but that's obvious). Use `ENVIRON` if they might contain backslashes.